# Software licensing case study

Tags: licensing

I have devoloped an snmp agent simulator application using java. I want to license it. I am a fresher in this area and i don't know more. Can anyone suggest a best mechanism for licensing my application. Thanks and regards

Comment: Open source or commercial license?

Comment: The first place to look .. would not be here.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think this question is better suited for http://superuser.com/. Have you had a look through the existing licenses..? Is your product commercial?

Comment: ya. it's a commercial product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several types of licensing for software

[Here's](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.html) a good page on how to use GNU licenses to your project OR [here](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html#SEC4)

Some example licenses (free):

**GPL:** allows commercial redistribution but the source code of the whole thing must be available (with changes) to anyone who purchases a copy of it .

**LGPL** is good for software libraries. These can be included in proprietary projects without needing to redistribute the whole source. The only time source distribution needs to happen is if they edit your code and even then, they only have to release their changes to it.

**MIT** code can be relicensed freely. Somebody could take your code, verbatim, and re-release it under GPL, proprietary licenses, etc.

**License choice:**

If you want to support free software, don't use too free a license. Disallowing commercial use gives free software an edge over proprietary programs. In theory with some licenses re-usage of your code must credit your original. But re-usage is difficult to proof and some corporations might just not credit you. However, if you do want to spread your software as wide as possible, i.e you don't care about commercial products using your software, then use MIT or LGPL. If in doubt use the more restrictive license and add a line, saying you may consider permitting uses outside of the license terms on a by-case basis. This way commercial users with a project worthy of your work have a chance.

**Copyright dispute:**

Include as much information as you dare to make proving it's really your brainchild easier. Have a lawsuit over the ownership in the back of your head. Poor man's copyright is mailing a printed copy of your source to your home address. If the envelope is unbroken, the postmark is valid evidence at court and provides a date and a verified address. An e-mail instead of your full name to identify you should be okay and sufficient proof but: Better safe, than sorry.

Comment: oops. I posted for a free product. I'm leaving it up just in case its useful to someone